# What is available in the withRest closure?

Tags: grails, groovy, httpbuilder

The [REST Client](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html) of [HTTP Builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/) has a `withRest` closure. How can I tell what is available in this closure:

```
    withRest(uri: domainName) { what,parameters,are,available,here ->
    }
```

The source is [here](https://github.com/berngp/grails-rest/blob/master/RestGrailsPlugin.groovy) (line 80 seems like a good place to start).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `groovyx.net.http.RESTClient` class. The JavaDoc should give you some idea of the things you can do with `withRest`

- [Grails - Rest Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest)
- [Groovy - RestClient JavaDoc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/RESTClient.html)